# google app engine upload/download data to NDB

Tags: app-engine-ndb

I have initial ndb to store data:

```
class Node(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  tag_list = ndb.TextProperty(repeated=True)
  center_point = ndb.GeoPtProperty()
```

I'd like to import data from CSV file. Please show me the ways to import data! and the structure of csv file.

Comment: In my Django project I've been using the `appcfg.py` script to `upload_data`. If that is the case for you, let me know, and I can add a more detailed answer.

Comment: I solved my problem by import csv, because i have a huge GIS data. I used script to import & test, split import data(1000 records) to multiple taskes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('nodes.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    node = Node(
        name = row[0]
        tag_list = row[1].split(",")
    )
    node.put()
```

nodes.csv

```
name1,"tag1,tag2",""
name2,"tag3,tag4",""
name3,"tag3,tag2",""
```

untested.